# Appium doctor output - question marks

Tags: appium

I cant tell if output from appium doctor says it is rly OK. Question marks make me unsure. Is this output rly OK?

[image: Appium-doctor screen output]

Answer (score 0):

Yes My friend. Everything seems to be perfect! Congratulations.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Share some error messages